# How to catch an exception while initializing an object?

Tags: java, exception, aem, java-threads

When I initialise the object

```
SignInfo signInfo = signService.create(signConfiguration, file.getContent(), customSignInfo);
```

then an exception is visible in the error.log file:

```
SignEvidenceVerificationException: Error occurs while evidence verification (statusCode: censored)
```

but the object `signInfo` is created properly but i would need to change some properties of the object. So my question is: How can I catch this exception? I already tried it with

```
try {
  SignInfo signInfo = signService.create(signConfiguration, file.getContent(), customSignInfo);
} catch (SignEvidenceVerificationException | SignException e ) {
```

Even in the debug mode i'm not able to step in to this exception. As it's only visible in the logfiles and not in the debuger.
As far i understand, this exception is thrown in a thread from an external library. How can I access that thread?

Comment: If this exception is a RuntimeException you shouldn't catch it. Why this exceptions happens?, maybe you have an issue in your configuration or something

Comment: @karelss Yes it is a RuntimeException. It happens because the user is not allowed to use a service and I need to programmaticaly notice that exception so that i can change his service level which is stored in the signInfo object

Comment: This shouldn't be a RuntimeException, should be a CheckedException but in this case you have to catch Exception directly, beware that this will catch other exceptions also, so you should check if the catched exception is the one you want otherwise rethrow it

Comment: Catching Exception or Throwable is not a good practice but sometimes you have to deal with situations like the one you are facing.